# What is the meter in the top right of Dauntless for?

Tags: dauntless

There is a meter in the top right of my screen and I notice that the percent keeps going up as the game goes on. What happens when it reaches 100% and how do I keep it from going up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [the Danger meter](https://playdauntless.com/news/what-is-the-danger-meter/). It will slowly increase while fighting a behemoth and while downed, and can be decreased by making a behemoth flee the area or reviving downed allies. If the meter reaches 100% players can't be revived anymore, and the behemoth hits much harder.